# xslt group by - php

Tags: php, xml, xslt, grouping

Hey i have the foolowing xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <accidents>
 <accident>
  <org>1</org>
  <com>194</com>
  <dep>010</dep>
  <grav>0.64</grav>
 </accident>
 <accident>
  <org>1</org>
  <com>194</com>
  <dep>420</dep>
  <grav>0.54</grav>
 </accident>
 <accident>
  <org>1</org>
  <com>44</com>
  <dep>010</dep>
  <grav>0.4</grav>
 </accident>
</accidents>
```

And i want to apply an xslt 1.0 to  have the number of accidents by dep :
the out put should be like this :

dep 010 : 2 accidents ; dep 420 : 1 accidents

thanks ,note i use php so the saxon cant be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kAccByDept" match="accident" use="dep"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "accident
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kAccByDept', dep)[1])
     ]">
     <xsl:if test="position() > 1"> ; </xsl:if>

     <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat('dep ', dep, ' : ',
              count(key('kAccByDept', dep)), ' accidents')
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<accidents>
    <accident>
        <org>1</org>
        <com>194</com>
        <dep>010</dep>
        <grav>0.64</grav>
    </accident>
    <accident>
        <org>1</org>
        <com>194</com>
        <dep>420</dep>
        <grav>0.54</grav>
    </accident>
    <accident>
        <org>1</org>
        <com>44</com>
        <dep>010</dep>
        <grav>0.4</grav>
    </accident>
</accidents>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
dep 010 : 2 accidents ; dep 420 : 1 accidents
```

**Explanation**:

1. **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.
2. **[Push style of XSLT processing](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/pushpull.html)**.

**Update**: The OP doesn't have available a true XSLT processor -- his tool doesn't implement `xsl:key`

**In this case the following solution (note -- this is much less efficient than Muenchian grouping) still solves the problem and *produces the exact wanted output***:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match=
      "accident
        [not(dep
            =
             preceding-sibling::*/dep
             )
        ]
      ">
         <xsl:value-of select=
          "concat('dep ', dep, ' : ',
                  count(following-sibling::*[dep = current()/dep]) +1,
                  ' accidents')
          "/>

         <xsl:if test=
         "following-sibling::*/dep
              [not(. = current()/dep)
              and
               not(.
            =
             ../preceding-sibling::*/dep)
              ]"> ; </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), the same wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
dep 010 : 2 accidents ; dep 420 : 1 accidents
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer ,i tried before the Muenchian method for grouping but  didnt work , i get the same error of your solution :  not implemented key and not implemented strip-space

Comment: @user986586: See my updated answer -- the solution produces *exactly* the wanted answer, unlike Kirill's solution.

Comment: @user986586: You mentioned that you use PHP. PHP(5)'s [`XSLTProcessor`](http://php.net/class.xsltprocessor) is a wrapper for libxslt. libxslt supports `<xsl:key/>` and `key()`. Maybe you should update libxslt and/or PHP.

Comment: Thanks again for your response , it's working but i want now to have the output as an html page like this   <table>
    
    <thead>
     <tr>
      
      <th>420</th>
      <th>010</th>
      
      
     </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
     
     <tr>
      <th>accidents</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      
      
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>

Comment: @user986586: This is a radical change of the requirements. Your current question has been fully answered. Please, ask a new question with the new requirements. Please, accept the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to use XSLT for this, but if you must you can more easily create dom elements from PHP values:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents('accidents.xml'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$deps = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('/accidents/accident/dep') as $node) {
   $n = $node->nodeValue;
   if (!isset($deps[$n])) {
      $deps[$n] = 0;
   }
   $deps[$n]++;
}
```

This gives an array with the "dep" as the key and the accident number as the value.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need to use xsl to respect the architecture of this project

Comment: Can you not use any PHP at all?  The values can still be inserted into an xsl stylesheet through DOM manipulation.

Comment: No i have to use an xml and xsl file ,and using a jquery plugin i show the result in an html page

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:key name="k" match="accident" use="dep"/>

  <xsl:template match="/accidents">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="accident[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', dep))]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="accident">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('dep ', dep, ' : ', count(key('k', dep)), ' accidents; ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Solution without Muenchian method:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/accidents">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="accident[not(preceding-sibling::accident/dep = dep)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="accident">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('dep ', dep, ' : ', count(../accident[dep = current()/dep]), ' accidents; ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
dep 010 : 2 accidents; dep 420 : 1 accidents;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I'm not sure why solutions using keys aren't working for you, but here's one that doesn't, which might work as a workaround:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="list">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($list,1,string-length($list)-2)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="accident">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::accident[dep = current()/dep])">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('dep ',dep,' : ',count(. | following-sibling::accident[dep = current()/dep]),' accidents ;')" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It outputs only where an `accident` element has no preceding siblings with the same `dep`, counting itself and all following `accident` elements witht he same `dep`. It assigns the result to a variable then using substring to chop off the trailing `;`. If that's actually not an issue, you can easily leave out the `match="/"` template altogether.